# Why is Sellmeier's equation an even function of $\lambda$?

Tags: optical-materials

According to [Sellmeier's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sellmeier_equation), the dispersion formula of a transparent material can be written as
$$n^2(\lambda) = 1 +\sum_i\frac{B_i \lambda^2}{\lambda^2 - C_i},$$ where $B_i$ and $C_i$ are empirically-determined  material constants. When written this way the formula assumes explicitly that the function $n^2(\lambda)$ is even. What justifies this assumption?

Comment: I suppose it's related to the analytical form of the [universal resonance curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance#Universal_resonance_curve).

Comment: As noted, the Sellmeier equation is an empirical relationship.

Answer (score 0):

What would a negative value of the wavelength mean?  Well, frequently we *define*
$$\lambda=\frac{2\pi}{\left|\vec{k}\right|},$$
in terms of the wave vector $\vec{k}$, which would make $\lambda$ nonnegative by defintion.  However, if we restrict attention to waves propagating along a single axis, say $\vec{k}=k\hat{z}$, we can allow for either positive or negative values of $\lambda$,
according to
$$\lambda=\frac{2\pi}{k}.$$
This means that a negative value of $\lambda$ just corresponds to a wave propagating in the opposite direction relative to a positive $\lambda$. In an isotropic material, the index of refraction does not depend on the direction.*  So the formula for $n(\lambda)$ is necessarily going to give an even function, so that the speed is the same in the $z$-direction or the $-z$-direction.

*It is, of course, possible to have asymmetric media, but the Sellmeier formula does not apply to those cases.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what  $-\lambda$ might mean. Instead a quasi-empirical formula such Sellmeier's could equally have a term such as $A\lambda$